# The curious case of Dmitri Valtane

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, the-undiscovered-country

In the *Voyager* episode ["Flashback"](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/225.htm), we learn that Tuvok was once a junior science officer aboard Sulu's Excelsior, and that he had been present at the moment of death of **Lt. Cmdr. Dmitri Valtane** during the events of *Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country*.

[image]

If we follow the events as they were presented in "Flashback", then Valtane would have died well before the Excelsior arrived at Khitomer to aid Kirk's Enterprise in the film's climactic battle.

However, at the end of *The Undiscovered Country*, we see Valtane alive and well on the Enterprise viewscreen (he is the leftmost officer, with the goatee):

[image]

**In-universe, what is the truth regarding Dmitri Valtane?  Did he survive the events of *Star Trek VI* or did he perish on the bridge of the Excelsior, only to appear as some kind of...*Force ghost*?**

Comment: Um... he got better...

Comment: @Politank-Z : Hehe.  But he definitely died in "Flashback" --- **JANEWAY:** *When Valtane died just now, it seemed to cause the memory to resurface.*

Comment: Memory Beta says: "According to Tuvok's virus-affected memory of the events, Valtane was killed in the battle when a console exploded. However in reality, Valtane survived the attack and was later seen on duty when the Excelsior joined the Enterprise-A in orbit of Khitomer."

Comment: I would have to see the scene from the movie again to verify that that has any further validity.

Comment: @Politank-Z : If that interpretation can be backed up with a quote from someone from the creative staff, that would be a solid answer.  :-)

Comment: I am realizing that the scene in Flashback where Valtane dies isn't paralleled in the movie. I can think of no better way, in-universe, to reconcile Flashback to the movie than what is described in the Memory Beta quote, but I haven't been able to find any creator confirmation.

Comment: @Politank-Z : Indeed, the Valtane "death" scene doesn't happen in the film, only in the episode.  If there is a Memory Beta article on this, that means there is a novel, comic, or short story in which this reconciliation is mentioned.  An answer with a citation to the appropriate extended universe material is acceptable, in the absence of canon or official statements.  You can always post that as an answer and then still hunt for a statement from a writer or producer.  :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Dmitri_Valtane), the wiki for licensed Star Trek works, including novels, comic books, RPG sourcebooks, video games and any other licensed works:

> Following Captain Hikaru Sulu's attempt to cross into Klingon space and rescue Captain James T. Kirk and Doctor Leonard McCoy from the Klingons, the Excelsior came under heavy fire from Klingon warships. According to Tuvok's virus-affected memory of the events, Valtane was killed in the battle when a console exploded. However in reality, Valtane survived the attack and was later seen on duty when the Excelsior joined the Enterprise-A in orbit of Khitomer.

This version of events is further substantiated in the licensed novel [The Fearful Summons](https://books.google.com/books?id=o32Hyl8FoR8C&pg=PT302&dq=star%20trek%20The%20Fearful%20Summons&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjW7pqy6dXKAhUK42MKHZ1RAQUQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=valtane&f=false):

> Sulu looked up at Commander Sencus. When his original science officer, Masoud **Valtane**, **had been transferred to another assignment**...

The Fearful Summons was written by [Denny Martin Flinn](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0282364/?ref_=fn_al_nm_1), who is credited as the co-writer of Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country.

On the one hand, this substantiates Valtane's survival in the eyes of one of the movie's creators. On the other hand, as one can see by Valtane's change in first name, The Fearful Summons was published before Flashback was aired; the Voyager creators didn't feel themselves beholden to Flinn's interpretation.

Out of universe, this appears to have been an oversight; the Voyager creators either overlooked Valtane's appearance at the end of the movie, or simply failed to establish his survival on screen.

In-universe, we are left with a contradiction. With or without the off-screen evidence, the best reconciliation between the contradictory inputs appears to be the explanation provided by Memory Beta.

Comment: Actually, if a novel written by a co-writer of the film gives the name as "Masoud Valtane", then the script itself might have "Masoud" as the officer's name.  On the other hand, it might leave the officer unnamed.  Either way, there's nothing to contradict the idea that the Excelsior might have **two Valtanes** --- twin brothers, Masoud and Dmitri.  Dmitri was killed but Masoud was not on the bridge at the time and survived.  We have "the Delaney sisters" on Voyager, so why not the Valtane brothers on the Excelsior?

Comment: Both bridge officers of the same rank on the same ship? Not impossible, but given the odds of identical twins in the first place, I think I'll let my answer stand.

Comment: "This character had no first name in Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country; it wasn't established as "Dmitri" until "Flashback". The name wasn't included in the first draft of the episode's script, but was in the final draft of that teleplay."

Comment: "Both bridge officers of the same rank on the same ship? Not impossible" - I wouldn't be too surprised. In college, I knew of a pair of identical twin girls who got identical final scores, went on to work in the same company, and whose boyfriends were a pair of identical twin boys! However I'd imagine if this were the intention on the show, a line would have been thrown in...